# Segmentation Fault with string compare

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

When working with a basic example like this, I am getting a segmentation fault.  I believe it's due to the size of the data not being fixed.  How can I have variable length data attached to a struct?

```
struct Node {
    char * data;
    struct Node* next;
};

void compareWord(struct Node** head_ref, char * new_data) {
  if (strcmp((*head_ref)->data, new_data) > 0) {
      head_ref->data = new_data;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  struct Node* head = NULL;
  head->data = "abc";
  char buf[] = "hello";
  compareWord(&head, buf);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't show printWord function,  Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Home much memory is allocated to `head` before you try and use it?? (hint, it is a pointer initialized `NULL`... guaranteed to segfault if you try and make use of it before allocating memory for it)

Comment: @OldProgrammer typo fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `How can I have variable length data attached to a struct?`

Answer is - **No**, you cannot. The reason is the size of the struct should be known at compile time.

The reason for segmentation fault is, your program is accessing `head` pointer before allocating memory to it:

```
  struct Node* head = NULL;
  head->data = "abc";
```

Allocate memory before using `head`:

```
  struct Node* head = NULL;
  head = malloc (sizeof(struct Node));
  if (NULL == head)
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  head->data = "abc";
```

Make sure to free allocated memory once you have done with it.

---

There is something known as [Flexible Array Member(FAM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) introduced in C99 standard. It may be of your interest.